# How do I make a variable in a struct equal to any value without a warning? (C)

Tags: c, struct

So I have a simple struct that looks like

```c
struct var {
    char* name;
    int value;
}
```

and I don't know how to avoid `warning: assignment makes integer from [non-int] without a cast [-Wint-conversion]` when I try to make value a non-integer, which I'll be doing a lot.  I know I shouldn't worry about a warning, but I really want to get rid of it, so what's the best way to fix this? Example of what I want to do:

```c
int main() {
    struct var a[100];
    a[0].name = "a";
    a[0].value = "c";
    a[1].name = "b";
    a[1].value = 0;
}
```

Comment: You should worry about this warning. Why are you trying to put a non-integer into an integer variable?

Comment: *Why* are you trying to assign a non-integer to an integer?  What is the type of the thing you are trying to assign from?

Comment: `what's the best way to fix this?` Don't assign a a '[non-int]' to an integer.

Comment: Most warnings are because you're doing something you shouldn't. They're classified as warnings because there are some situations where they make sense, but if you're a beginner it's more likely you're not in one of those situations.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal, reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Use a type that can hold any value you might put in it (for numbers only, maybe a double would work)?  Or use a union if you need to.  But also consider how you'll know, later, what type you stored.

Comment: If you post some actual code, we can help you understand what you're doing wrong and how to do it correctly.

Comment: If this is something like a general purpose hash table, consider using a `void*` pointer and dynamically allocating the value.

Comment: How might I do that with a void*? Sorry, I'm very bad with memory management

Comment: `a[0].value = {};` is not valid. Not sure what you want to here.

Comment: Alright, fixed that with `a[0].value = {}`.  A lot of people were talking about giving code so I came up with that really quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to use a `union` inside of the struct with fields for each type you want to support:

```
struct var {
    char* name;
    char type;
    union {
        int i;
        char c;
        char *s;
        float f;
        double d;
    } value;
};
```

The `type` field can be used to determine which field of the union is active:

```
struct var a[100];
a[0].name = "a";
a[0].type = 's';
a[0].value.s = "c";
a[1].name = "b";
a[0].type = 'i';
a[1].value.i = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the naming conventions you're using, I'm assuming `struct var` is meant to store key-value pairs, where the value can be any type.  Unfortunately, C is statically typed - if you declare `value` as an `int`, it can *only* store `int` values.  If you assign a floating-point value to it, that value will be converted to an integer and you will lose the fractional portion.  You can't use it to store a string or any other aggregate type.

You basically have two options.  You can make `value` a *union* of different types:

```
enum var_type { INTEGER, FLOATING, STRING };
struct var
{
  char *name;
  enum var_type type;
  union {
    int i;
    double f;
    char *s;
  } value;
};
```

and then you can store different types to different members of the union:

```
struct var v[3];
v[0].name = "foo";
v[0].type = INTEGER;
v[0].value.i = 1;

v[1].name = "bar";
v[1].type = FLOATING;
v[1].value.f = 3.14;

v[2].name = "bletch";
v[2].type = STRING;
v[2].value.s = "this is a test";
```

This approach, while not involving dynamic memory and all the heartburn that comes with it, is a pain.  You have to make sure you have a union member for every type you want to represent, and if that changes you have to hack the type and rebuild. You have to assign to the specific union member.

Another approach is to make `value` a simple `void *`, and then dynamically allocate and assign memory to it.  While this introduces memory management headaches, it's more flexible and easier to abstract.

```
struct var {
  char *name;
  void *value;
};

struct var v[3];
v[0].name = "foo";
v[0].value = copy_int( 1 );

v[1].name = "bar";
v[1].value = copy_float( 3.14 );

v[2].name = "bletch";
v[2].value = copy_string( "this is a test" );
```

where each of `copy_int`, `copy_float`, and `copy_string` are functions that abstract away the `malloc` calls and assignments:

```
void *copy_int( int arg )
{
  int *mem = malloc( sizeof *mem );
  if ( mem )
    *mem = arg;
  return mem;
}

void *copy_float( double arg )
{
  double *mem = malloc( sizeof *mem );
  if ( mem )
    *mem = arg;
  return mem;
}

void *copy_string( const char *str )
{
  char *mem = malloc( sizeof *mem * (strlen( str ) + 1 ));
  if ( mem )
    strcpy( mem, str );
  return mem;
}
```

The beauty of this method is that you don't have to hack your `struct var` type every time you want to store a different type of value - you only have to implement a new `copy_*` function.

However...

You still need some way to determine what the type of `value` is when you want to use it later on.  You can either the `enum` method above to explicitly tag it, or you can add a function pointer member and create functions to return information about the type, like so:

```
struct var {
  char *name;
  void *value;
  char *(*type)( void );
};

char *int_type( void ) { return "int"; }
char *double_type( void ) { return "double"; }
char *string_type( void ) { return "string"; }
...
struct var v[3];
v[0].name = "foo";
v[0].type = int_type;
v[0].value = copy_int( 1 );
...
if ( strcmp( v[0].type(), "int" ) )
{
  printf( "%s = %d\n", v[0].name, *((int *) v[0].value) );
}
```

Again, the beauty of this approach is you don't have to hack your struct or the enum when you want to add new value types - you only have to implement the functions to copy and indicate type.

Comment: I have a question. If I call `copy_int(5)` how do I access the value I stored in it later on so I can output `5` and not `null` or `0`?

Comment: @Dock: See my edit - you'd need to cast the `value` member to a pointer of the appropriate type and then dereference.  This is a major weakness with this approach; you have to get into casting and dereferencing gymnastics.  There are better ways to abstract this sort of thing out, but it eventually gets to be a lot of code.  C just isn't built to handle type polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

### Using a union is probably not what you want

As @dbush stated, a union will fix your immediate problem. However, this is like using a flamethrower to erase a whiteboard. It works, but it will cause more problems later on.

### Why this is the code yelling at you

C has a type system. It helps you check if what you're assigning to the variable has the same type as what the variable is. It doesn't really make sense to say `int = "hello" + 1`. Something similar is happening in your question. What does `int value = "c"` mean?

### What should I do instead?

The real answer is one you won't like. You probably shouldn't assign a letter to a number. This is what the warning is telling you. We can't really answer what you should be doing as we would need to have more knowledge of your code.

### Why is it a warning and not an error?

Using the ASCII format, each letter has an equivalent number. In more advanced programs, you might need to assign the number representing the letter into a variable with a numeric type. You usually don't want to do this (so it's a warning) but sometimes you really want to do that, and the compiler knows how to do it if you really want to (which is why it is not an error).